# How to access various databases using OLE DB with minimum installation

Tags: database, crystal-reports, installation, oledb

Our reporting tool needs to access the database and get information from it. The tool uses **Crystal Reports**. The database can be one of **SQL Server**, **Oracle**, **Sybase** and **Postgres**. Currently, we install the database client with the report tool installation. We would like to avoid this client installation due to licensing issues and user privileges – we want non-admins to be able to install the tool as well.

Is there a way to access all of these databases without having to install their client software?

As I said, our tool uses **Crystal Reports** to generate reports, and Crystal connects to the database using **OLE DB**.

Answer (score 1):

Where/how are you setting up the connection?

I created a basic Crystal viewer that attaches to data in SQL Server, Access and Oracle. The connection is embedded into each report at design time, using a specific Crystal Reports login on each server, to control permissions.

This allows the viewer to be installed for any user. The reports are developed by the Crystal team and stored centrally for anyone to use (assuming they have access to the report directory).

Comment: The question is what is installed for each user. I'm interested in minimum required installation, and that's why I'm after a general driver that won't require specific DB installation.

Comment: I install the viewer application on the user machine and hold the reports centrally. The database connection is stored in the Crystal Report. That way, the reporting application doesn't need direct access to any database, and therefore no local drivers; it all works through Crystal.